# Fetching data through URL works on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, api, url, curl

Same code works on localhost. When trying to use same code on server then its not fetching out any data.
I am breaking my head for this, please help me out for this.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://52.66.102.121:8000/?fromstop=THANE(THANE)&tostop=PUNE(PUNE)&jrdt=25-05-17';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r ($result);
?>
```

Comment: You should at least show the code that you think is broken.

Comment: How exactly are we supposed to help you out when you haven't told us what you're actually doing?

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: Getting blank page.

Answer (score 1):

In php.ini make url fopen to on and give it a try.

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

From your above code posted, I assume you should have not enabled curl in server. Please confirm if its already enabled.

Comment: I dont think any issue in your code, it might be issue of the server firewall or something.

Comment: Might be but how to resolve it? file_get_contents(); also working on localhost, not one server

Comment: hmmm, open port 8080 and try it should work. Do not forgot to remove port from URL or add 8080 port in url

Comment: We can not change url as it is MSRTC url.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information like code which is not working on the server. Also, check PHP version used on local and on the server.

Comment: this isn't an answer

Comment: Now I can see the code :) and it seems fine to me. if file_get_contents is also not working on your server then ask the server guys to confirm that allow_url_fopen setting in your ini file is not getting overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both are hit same URL and check your PHP version also local and server and don't give any static URL like http://localhost/